# How to sort by descending datetime ng-repeat in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to sort my data by descending date, ie 27, 26 , 25 .... How to do this?

```
<tbody class="gradeX" ng-repeat="x in Profile | orderBy: x.created_datetime">
  <tr>
    <td>{{x.job_title }}</td>
    <td>{{x.created_datetime | date:'medium' }}</td>
    <td>{{x.updated_datetime | date:'medium' }}</td>
    <td>{{x.status}}</td>
    <td>{{ x.total }}</td>
    <td class="actions"> <a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show Invoice Details" ng-click="activeinvoicesCtrl.setCurrentJob(x)"><i class="fa fa-server fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: English, formatting of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a string with the name of the property your are looking for.
In case it is a nested property use the . to concat the string, like 'item.created_datetime'

```
<tbody class="gradeX" ng-repeat="x in Profile | orderBy: '-created_datetime'">
```

Comment: i want lastest date time on top

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tbody class="gradeX" ng-repeat="x in Profile | orderBy: 'created_datetime'">
                                        <tr >
                                            <td>{{x.job_title }}</td>
                                            <td>{{x.created_datetime  | date:'medium' }}</td>
                                            <td>{{x.updated_datetime  | date:'medium' }}</td>
                                            <td>{{x.status}}</td>
                                         <td >{{ x.total }}</td>
                                         <td class="actions">
                          <a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show Invoice Details"  ng-click="activeinvoicesCtrl.setCurrentJob(x)"><i class="fa fa-server fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                        </td>                                       
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
```

Make sure your created_datetime object is a javascript Date() object, if not you might be surprised to see that 1 feb is before 2 jan.